# can not resolve Uncaught TypeError: vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default is undefined

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, webpack-dev-server

I am working on vue js 2 version and I needed to download font-awsome library for styling purpose. However, when I downloaded the files it seemed not compatible with my project so I deleted/uninstalled them (the font-awsome libraries), and then all of a sudden when I tried to refresh the server I got this error in the console :

> Uncaught TypeError: vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default is
> undefined

Note that the code was working fine before installing and uninstalling the the font-awsome libraries, I don't really know what happened I also did try to ctrl + z to restore the main.js but is still showing the same error.

1- main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import VueFirestore from 'vue-firestore'
import JQuery from 'jquery'
import {BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin} from 'bootstrap-vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'
import './assets/app.scss'
import swal from 'sweetalert2';
// import VoerroTagsInput from '@voerro/vue-tagsinput';

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(IconsPlugin)
window.$ = JQuery
Vue.use(VueFirestore, {
  key: 'id',         // the name of the property. Default is '.key'.
  enumerable: true  //  whether it is enumerable or not. Default is true.
})

Vue.use(VueFirestore)
Vue.config.productionTip = false
// Make BootstrapVue available throughout your project
// Vue.use(createPopper)

let app = '';

if(!app){
  new Vue({
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
  }).$mount("#app");
  
}

window.Swal = swal;
const Toast = Swal.mixin({
  toast: true,
  position: 'top-end',
  showConfirmButton: false,
  timer: 3000
});

window.Toast = Toast;
```

2- index.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'books',
    component: () => import('../components/books')
  },
]
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})
export default router
```

3- package.json:

```
{
  "name": "vue-firebase-crud",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.22.0",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "firebase": "^8.10.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.1",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.4.37",
    "vue-firestore": "^0.3.30",
    "vue-router": "^3.6.5",
    "vue2-editor": "^2.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.3",
    "sass": "^1.55.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.1.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

4- error in console:

[image]

Comment: what if you delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`, `reinstall` then build

Comment: thanks bro it worked with me now. I deleted and reinstall node_modules and package-lock.json. But am wondering why this error happen all of a sudden? what I should do to avoid it in future projects?